# How do I render a commandLink with action referring to a POJO from the backing bean in jsf2?

Tags: binding, jsf-2

I need to render an html table having precise control over rows, columns, headers, styles etc.
I'm using a primeFaces panelGrid this way:

```
<p:panelGrid binding="#{myBean.tableComponent}"/>
```

In my backing bean, I have:

```
private UIComponent tableComponent;

public UIComponent getTableComponent() {        
    if (tableComponent == null) {
        tableComponent = new PanelGrid();
        populateTableComponent(); // Populate datatable.
    }
    return tableComponent;
}

public void setTableComponent(UIComponent tableComponent) {
    this.tableComponent = tableComponent;
}

private void populateTableComponent() {
    PanelGrid tbl = (PanelGrid) tableComponent;
    //...
    for (MyPojo row : data.getRows) { 
        // ...here I create the row/column UIComponent subtree
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is:
For a specific column, I have to render a commandLink in each row.
This Link should AJAX-call a bean's method which should do something related to the clicked row.
Something like `<p:commandLink action="#{myBean.myFieldClick(***row***)}">` but
how can I refer to `row`?

Other ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Just use exactly the same variable name as definied in `var` attribute of the data table. In other words, write down exactly the same EL expression string as you would do when normally writing it in a view file instead of in a backing bean.

Thus, the action attribute of the following command link example in the view

```
<p:dataTable ... var="row">
    ...
    <p:commandLink ... action="#{myBean.myFieldClick(row)}">
```

could programmatically be represented as

```
MethodExpression action = createMethodExpression("#{myBean.myFieldClick(row)}", null, Row.class);
```

with this helper method

```
public static MethodExpression createMethodExpression(String expression, Class<?> returnType, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
        facesContext.getELContext(), expression, returnType, parameterTypes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, BalusC.  But, if I understand correctly, this should work for a `dataTable`. Here I haven't a `var` attribute because the iteration is in the backing bean code. (Sorry if I called my variable "tableComponent", but it's a `panelGrid`)